# Use an external rewrite engine with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, lua

I want to run a rewrite engine on my frontend servers (apache).

I have added this configuration

```
<If "-f 'PATH_TO_MY_LUA_SCRIPT'">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteMap cust "prg:PATH_TO_MY_LUA_SCRIPT"
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${cust:%{REQUEST_URI}}" [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
  </If>
```

But **Apache** says that `RewriteMap not allowed here`

PS : Of course `PATH_TO_MY_LUA_SCRIPT` is replaced by the full path (and my script is executable)
Has anyone used an external **rewrite** lua scriupt with **Apache** `2.4` ?

Answer (score 0):

See [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) documentation

> Context: server config, virtual host

And [`Context`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) means

> Context
>
> This indicates where in the server's configuration files the directive is legal. It's a comma-separated list of one or more of the following values:
>
> - server config ...
> - virtual host ...
> - directory ...
> - .htaccess ...
>
> The directive is *only* allowed within the designated context; if you try to use it elsewhere, you'll get a configuration error that will either prevent the server from handling requests in that context correctly, or will keep the server from operating at all -- i.e., the server won't even start.

So you cannot use `RewriteMap` in an .htaccess file, only in the main or in a virtual host configuration.

---

In this case [`If`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#if) is causing the failure, because

> Only directives that support the directory context can be used within this configuration section.

But `RewriteMap` may not be used in a directory context. So even if you have it in the main or virtual host configuration, you must not use it inside an `If` directive.

Comment: Ok understood. So can I defined conditionally the program path (my rewrite script)

Comment: What is the reason for a conditional directive? Either the command is installed or it is not, and if it is not installed, you may comment the section.

Comment: in fact, is to avoid downtime.
I mean, I have a `rewrite.lua` script (my custom rewrite engine) and I need apache to read it. however, I have no access to configuration (sysadmins does but not devs). so to activate, I have to activate this directive after `rewrite.lua` is deployed on all my nodes.

But I could find a solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I forget to precise.

This conf is not in my `.htaccess` but in the **main vhost config**